# Calling scripts from inside other scripts

Tags: shell-script, cron

I have a script which I call every 10 minutes with a cronjob:

> */10 * * * * ~/mydirectory/myscript.sh

Now, inside `~/mydirectory` there is also another script, let's say `myotherscript.sh` which I'd like to call from inside `myscript.sh`. Both scripts have been `chmod`'ed to be executable and when I execute `myscript.sh` from the command line inside `~/mydirectory` everything works fine. I execute it as follows:

> . myscript.sh

But it doesn't look like the cronjob works. When I remove the reference to the second script from inside the primary script, it works though so I suspect there is something wrong with the way I reference the second script. This is what the contents of `myscript.sh` looks like:

```
#! /bin/bash
do-something
do-something-else
. myotherscript.sh
```

Could it be that, when the cronjob runs, the current directory is not `~/mydirectory` and so the cronjob can't find the `myotherscript.sh` file? If so, how to I get it to see the file? I don't want to specify the absolute path inside the primary script as I might want to move it (and `myotherscript.sh`) to another directory at some point or I might want to rename `~/mydirectory` at some point and I don't then want to have to change the contents of `myscript.sh` to reference the new absolute path.

BONUS QUESTION: Right now, when it's time for the cronjob to execute I basically just hold thumbs and hope for the best but I have no way of seeing whether it was successful and if it failed, why it failed. Any tips on how I can see why the cronjob didn't execute as expected?

Answer (score 5):

OK, so glenn jackman's answer works and it also answered my bonus question but I have since figured out another and what I believe to be more elegant way of making sure the cronjob runs in the directory in which the scripts are located.

Simply by replacing

```
*/10 * * * * ~/mydirectory/myscript.sh
```

with

```
*/10 * * * * cd ~/mydirectory && ./myscript.sh
```

And that solves the problem. Everything works.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the script incorrectly. It should be:

```
#! /bin/bash
do-something
do-something-else
./myotherscript.sh;
```

Comment: Would you mind quickly explaining what the difference between . myotherscript.sh and ./myotherscript.sh is?

Comment: Well im not sure what `. myotherscript.sh` actually does. I just know through my experience that when I was to call a script within a script I would simply add ./myotherscript.sh;`

Comment: But if i was to guess with glenn's answer, it seems that the `.` refers to the pwd and then using `./script.sh` calls the script...

Comment: `.` is the shell's "source" command that reads the script and executes it in the current shell.

Comment: Thanks glenn, and what does ./script.sh mean?

Comment: That means you're launching the script in a separate process. The difference is important if the other script declares some variables or functions, or changes to another directory, and you rely on those effects in the current shell: `. ./other` will keep those "side effects" in the current shell; if you use a separate process `./other`, then the side effects disappear when the process exits.

Answer (score 2):

`myscript` should have:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
. ./myotherscript.sh
```

When cron launches your script, the $PWD might be `/` so you should go to where your script is located if you want to use relative paths.

You may find it useful to log your script's output:

```
*/10 * * * * ~/mydirectory/myscript.sh 2>&1 | /usr/bin/ts '[%FT%T]' >> ~/mydirectory/myscript.log
```

`ts` adds a timestamp to each line of input. On Fedora and Ubuntu, it's in the `moreutils` package.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the syntax of     cd "$(dirname "$0")"? When I add exactly that into me script and try to run it from the command line I get an error "dirname: invalid option -- 'b'"

Comment: @DewaldSwanepoel - read Glenn's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5708339).

Comment: @don_crissti, good find. I totally forgot about that.

Comment: Don't use `dirname` here - it has the *(admittedly extremely unlikely)* chance of mangling the directory name which you want to print. `cd -- "${0%/*}"` will work as well *(if either will work at all - if the script being run sets `$0` somehow to anything other than a fully qualified path then you're SOL in both cases)*.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a PATH and MAILTO within the crontab should help.